# Developing a Reward Box Algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, probability

I'm trying to build a probability algorithm that will give the user his/her reward based on these probabilities.

1 $ - 60%

2 $ - 25%

5 $ - 12%

10 $ - 1.99%

50 $ - 1%

500 $ - 0.01%

How can I do that? Can you give me any examples of code? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the `rand` function here. Multiply all the probabilities by 100 to be able to work with the integral types, with their total sum being 10000. Generate a random number between 1 and 10000. Now, for the chances to be 60%, if the random number is between, say, 1 and 6000, the reward would be 1$, and so on for other probabilities.

```
<?php

function reward() {

    $random = rand(1, 10000);

    if($random >= 1 && $random <= 6000) {
        $reward = 1;
    } else if($random > 6000 && $random <= 8500) {
        $reward = 2;
    } else if($random > 8500 && $random <= 9700) {
        $reward = 5;
    } else if($random > 9700 && $random <= 9899) {
        $reward = 10;
    } else if($random > 9899 && $random <= 9999) {
        $reward = 50;
    } else {
        $reward = 500;
    }

    return $reward;
}

echo reward();

?>
```

Comment: hey I've actually made my own solution by using an array and filling it with all the numbers with for loops and array_push, though your solution seems more optimized, just out of curiosity how much performance difference do you think there would be

Comment: Can't do the exact comparison since I don't know your exact implementation. You can use `microtime` to compare the run times. This function runs in about 2E-5 seconds.

Comment: Your algorithm is better (ofc) tested it the difference is at least 15-30%